# Kendo events do not fire consistently

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got two kendo DDLs with change events attached. One fires fine, the other does not and fails silently. If I point the event that is not firing at a non-existent function it complains in the console. But pointing to an existing function does nothing. The only way I've found around this is to attach an onchange event to the underlying text input that is part of the kendo DDL.

```
<span class="wideitemtitle">Working DDL:</span>@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.WorkingDDLID).DataValueField("ID").DataTextField("Text").BindTo(Model.DDLWorking).OptionLabel("Select Working DDL").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;" }).Events(ev => ev.Change("workingDDLChanged"))

<span class="wideitemtitle">Broken DDL:</span>@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.BrokenDDLID).DataValueField("ID").DataTextField("Text").BindTo(Model.DDLBroken).OptionLabel("Select Broken DDL").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;" }).Events(ev => ev.Change("brokenDDLChanged"))
```

All I have in the attached functions are console.logs.

```
function workingDDLChanged(e)
{
console.log('in workingDDLChanged');
}

function brokenDDLChanged(e)
{
console.log('in brokenDDLChanged');
}
```

The first one fires fine, the second does not. No error message appears in the console and brokenDDLChanged never fires. The only way around it I could find was:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   document.getElementById('WorkingDDLID').onchange = brokenDDLChanged;
});
```

Where `WorkingDDLID` is the ID of the underlying text input field from which the kendo DDL is made.

Comment: Are these dropdown lists in a partial view?

Comment: @JamesS Yes, however all JS code is contained in script tags at the bottom of the partial view. I considered that it may be a name collision and changed the name of the function `brokenDDLChanged` to something random but it had no effect.

Comment: I know it may sound odd but, if you move the functions a layer up (ie the layer that implements the partial view) does it work then?

Comment: @JamesS No, if I move it up a layer it complains that the function is no longer defined.

Comment: @JamesS What I don't understand is why the function `workingDDLChanged` fires just fine if `brokenDDLChanged` doesn't. Both DDLs are defined directly adjacent to eachother and both functions are also defined next to each other.

Comment: Have you tried looking into seeing what happens when the dropdown is changed using Google DevTools? Where does ti go in the Network tab? My Only other 'guess' is that there is a javascript function somewhere above it that's syntax is either incorrect (ie missing a bracket) and so is causing everything defined below it to be invalid. Giving you a silent error

Comment: Try [deferring initialization](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/helper-basics/fundamentals) of the Kendo dropdowns until after the scripts are defined.

Comment: Use .Name("WorkingDDLID") and .Name("BrokenDDLID"). This fixed something similar for me.